# How to use the polygon tool in ITK SNAP for 3D/voxel?

Tags: itk

I know the paintbrush tool can segment out voxel 3D volume but how do I do this with the polygon tool? I want all slices to have the save segmentations.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by drawing your polygon on the first slice, accepting it, scrolling to the last slice, "paste last polygon", and then using Tool menu, option Interpolate Labels. Default options should give you the desired result.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple labels in the first/last slice. You can also do one label at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The polygon tool is used to paint closed polygons on top of the axial, sagittal and coronal slice windows.
[image: polygon tool]

These polygons are then filled with the currently selected label. By painting polygons slice by slice, a whole 3D structure can be selected.

Click the left mouse button somewhere on the boundary of the right caudate.

Continue clicking the left button along a sequence of points along the boundary.

[image: polygon test]

Click the right mouse button to close the polygon.The green rectangle around the polygon indicates that all of the vertices are currently selected. Selected vertices can be moved by clicking and dragging the left mouse button. Let's select some vertices and move them:

[image: polygon test2]

Use the mouse to draw a box around some of the vertices in the polygon (to draw the box, click and hold the left mouse button near the upper left part of the slice window, drag the mouse towards the lower right corner and release the button once the box contains two or more vertices).
Click and hold the left mouse button inside the green box and drag it to move the selected vertices.

In addition to selecting vertices and moving them, you can use the buttons located under each slice window to manipulate the polygon. Use the 'delete' button to delete the currently selected vertices from the polygon. Use the 'insert' button to insert new vertices between adjacent pairs of selected vertices.

Edit the polygon by selecting, moving, deleting and inserting vertices until you are satisfied with it.

Use the 'accept' button to fill the polygon with the segmentation label 'caudates'.

[image: polygon test 3]

Once you have clicked 'accept', the voxels inside of the polygon are assigned the currently selected segmentation label.

If you are not satisfied with your result and want to erase it, you can do so by changing the active drawing label to the 'Clear' label, and painting a polygon on top of the part of the segmentation that you want to erase. When you press 'accept', the voxels withing this polygon will be assigned the clear label.

SNAP remembers the last polygon that you used and lets you paste it. This makes segmenting a structure faster.

Move to the next slice in the slice window where you just painted (using the scroll bar or the mouse wheel).

Press the 'paste' button to recall the last accepted polygon.

[image: polygon test 4]

Edit the pasted polygon by selecting and moving vertices, and accept it when satisfied.